# CE Cache + Multilanguage

Tags: multi-language, ce-cache

I Use the [Multilanguage Add-On](http://biberltd.com/de/documentation/software/biber_ltd_multi_language_support/) from Bieber ltd. I now want also to ad caching to my site with CE Cache. I almost works but ce cache doesn't take the language segment in the url into account. The sites are delivered in one language no matter if domain.com/de or domain.com/en

I already fount a [devot:ee thread](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/support/ce-cache/viewthread/4638) but I don't know where to place and how to alter the string mentioned in this thread so the URI is correct. Anybody solved this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't used Bieber's add-on, but, from glancing at the docs, I believe you should use their `{language_code}` variable to feed CE Cache's `url_prefix` parameter (had to do something similar using Publisher on a multilingual site).

Something like this should do it, I think... maybe:

`{exp:ce_cache:ic url_prefix="{language_code}" ...}`